# Change child-view inside main-view Sencha Touch 2.4

Tags: extjs, sencha-touch-2, sencha-architect

I am learning sencha touch and extjs using citybars sample app provided by sencha itself.

Here is the link
http://docs.sencha.com/architect/3/tutorials/first_mobile_application.html

This app is very good for learning purpose and now i want to create an demo app in which i have following things:

1. There is a `mainview` which contains, static/fixed header (name `view1`).
2. Main view contains another view, let say `view2` which is variable or can be changed.

**Question**

How can i achieve this functionality in which `view2` change dynamically?

[image: Sample Image]

Answer (score 1):

I can guide you with what you want to achieve.

If you need a slide navigation then first try [this](http://www.senchatutorials.org/slide-navigation-sencha-touch/). 
I am providing you with an sample code which will give you some idea on your desired layout. Try this view:

```
Ext.define('Sample.view.Main', {
        extend: 'Ext.Container',
        xtype: 'main',
        requires: [
        'Ext.dataview.List'
        ],
        config: {
          layout: 'hbox',
          cls: 'main',
          items: [{
            xtype: 'list',
            itemTpl: '{title}',
            data: [{ title: 'Red', val: 'red' },
            { title: 'Blue', val: 'blue' },
            { title: 'Orange', val: 'orange' },
            { title: 'Purple', val: 'purple' }],
            flex: 1,
            listeners: {

                itemtap: function(el, index, target, record, e) {
                    var me = this,
                    element = Ext.get(e.target),
                    main = element.parent('.main'), //assign the dom of 'Main' view to 'main'
                    newCls = record.get('val');

                    if(me.lastAddedCls) {
                        main.removeCls(me.lastAddedCls).addCls(newCls);
                    } else {
                        main.addCls(newCls);
                    }

                    me.lastAddedCls = newCls; // Keeps track of last added view so that it can be further removed
                }
            }
        }, {
            cls: 'viewTwo',
            flex: 2
        }]
    }
});
```

Here suppose the first section is navigation panel and second section is you desired **variable view 2**.
You can now add some styling in a css file(say style.css)

```
.main.red {
    background-color: red;
}
.main.blue {
    background-color: blue;
}
.main.purple {
    background-color: purple;
}
.main.orange {
    background-color: orange;
}
```

NB: Don't forget to add this css file in `bootstrap.json` and `app.json` files.

I showed this example by changing the background color. You can try adding and removing views here.

Feel free to ask any query.

Comment: Thanks Anand. The provided link is very helpful. Thanks again :)

Comment: Welcome Mohit. Happy Coding :)

Answer (score 0):

You could use a TabPanel with a docked top toolbar. The TabPanel bottom bar would then allow your users to navigate between the views in your app.

A very simple example which you could build on for your own use:

```
Ext.create('Ext.TabPanel', {
    fullscreen: true,
    tabBarPosition: 'bottom',

    defaults: {
        styleHtmlContent: true
    },

    items: [
        {
            xtype: 'titlebar',
            docked: 'top',
            title: 'My title'
        },
        {
            title: 'Home',
            iconCls: 'home',
            html: 'Home Screen'
        },
        {
            title: 'Contact',
            iconCls: 'user',
            html: 'Contact Screen'
        }
    ]
});
```

The items would just be your own views created in Architect:

```
items: [
            {
                xtype: 'titlebar',
                docked: 'top',
                title: 'My title'
            },
            {
                xtype: 'mylistview',
                iconCls: 'home'
            },
            {
                xtype: 'mymapview',
                iconCls: 'map'
            }
        ]
```

Read more here => http://docs-origin.sencha.com/touch/2.4/2.4.1-apidocs/#!/api/Ext.tab.Panel

Comment: When i use `tabpanel`, it contains two tab button. I don't want them. Instead i want a textfield at center, a menu icon on left, such that when user clicks it, an overlay menu is shown. How can i achieve this?

Comment: OK well this is turning into a 'Someone write my code for me...' type of question I suggest you look at Ext.Menu in the docs which you could show\hide with a docked top toolbar button click handler.

Comment: I don't want you to write any code for me. I am just asking for some suggestions which helps me to use best practices of Sencha Touch :)